# PageRank - How is a link defined?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, wikipedia-api, pagerank

I am trying to learn more about the PageRank algorithm. I have a task to implement a wikipedia search engine implementation using PageRank. I wanted to know how a links are defined. So if Page A has a hyperlink in the wiki article to Page B, is that a link?

Also after I have calculated the PageRank values for all wiki pages. How can I use this exactly to compare with the search term to get the most relevant wiki pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a link. Once you have calculated the PageRank for each page, you need to build a *search index* sorted by PageRank.